# Website or book with Hasse diagrams of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, lattice-orders

I need to look at Hasse diagrams of very many groups, especially high powers of small symmetric groups.
Is there any place where I could look them up? Calculating them myself would be a huge amount of work.

Comment: If you know a programming language it's not terribly difficult to generate them. I hesitate to say no such resource exists because for all I know it does, but my gut feeling is that it wouldn't.

Comment: I have a feeling such Hasse diagrams might become useless quickly. I've looked at them for reasonably small 4- and 5-dimensional polytopes and it's just a giant blur of lines.

Comment: So...are there or not? Looks like you guys have seen them somewhere!

Comment: Useful: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html, https://hobbes.la.asu.edu/groups/groups.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

http://sheaves.github.io/Subgroup-Lattice/

This shows how to build the lattice in Sage, and at the very end of the third post there is a complete generator. 
(You can use Sage freely on websites like sagemath.org, or installing it on your computer.)

Comment: Nice find! I wasn't in any position to do any experimenting, but my hypothetical answer would basically have involved a mini Sage tutorial. I'm interested to know if your diagrams are too crowded to be useful (my experience in Sage was with Hasse diagrams of face lattices of polytopes, not subgroups of a group -- but I expect yours to get crowded quickly as well).